# PHP Calling a Function for input

Tags: php

Good day, I seem to have trouble in my PHP function where I would like to input 3 numbers and output the highest. Which part of my code prevents the numbers from displaying? I appreciate any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <hr>
    <form action="functioncall.php" method="post">
      Enter Number 1: <input type="number" name="n1"> <br>
      Enter Number 2: <input type="number" name="n2"> <br>
      Enter Number 3: <input type="number" name="n3"> <br>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <hr>

    <?php
      function getMax(){
        if(isset($_POST['n1']) >= isset($_POST['n2']) && isset($_POST['n1']) >= isset($_POST['n3'])){
          return isset($_POST['n1']);
        } elseif (isset($_POST['n2']) >= isset($_POST['n1']) && isset($_POST['n2']) >= isset($_POST['n3'])) {
          return isset($_POST['n2']);
        } else {
          return isset($_POST['n3']);
        }
      }

      echo getMax();

     ?>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `isset()` checks if a value is set, so all of your comparisons are checking if the various value are there and not comparing the actual values.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [`max`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

You have set if check as `(isset($_POST['n1']) >= isset($_POST['n2']))` which will not compare with actual values it compares with 1 & 0. And used return as `isset()` which will also return 0 or 1. Which makes your answer wrong.

```
function getMax(){
    if(($_POST['n1'] >= $_POST['n2']) && ($_POST['n1'] >= $_POST['n3'])){
        return ($_POST['n1']);
    } elseif (($_POST['n2'] >= $_POST['n1']) && ($_POST['n2'] >= $_POST['n3'])) {
        return ($_POST['n2']);
    } else {
        return ($_POST['n3']);
    }
}

echo getMax();
```

Answer (score 3):

Like others have mentioned, `isset()` just returns a boolean to see if the value is set.

There is a much better way to get the max using the PHP method `max()`:

See here http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

You could write the method like this to be a bit more simple:

```
<?php

function getMax(){
    $n1 = isset($_POST['n1']) ? $_POST['n1']: 0;
    $n2 = isset($_POST['n3']) ? $_POST['n2']: 0;
    $n3 = isset($_POST['n3']) ? $_POST['n3']: 0;

    return max($n1, $n2, $n3);
}
```

If you're using PHP 7+ you can do it this way because of the [Null coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

```
<?php

function getMax(){
    $n1 = $_POST['n1'] ?? 0;
    $n2 = $_POST['n2'] ?? 0;
    $n3 = $_POST['n3'] ?? 0;

    return max($n1, $n2, $n3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You return/use the `isset` result which is a boolean. Only use `isset` to check whether the input is provided, and use the number instead.

Answer (score 0):

you are returning the isset($_POST['n1']); which will return (1 or 0) or (true or false)

you need to just return $_POST['your input variable name']

replace all your return statement like

```
return $_POST['your input variable name'];
```

Comment: He is also comparing the `isset` results in the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing `input[submit]` in your html form.
Replace your html input submit button with this
`<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">`

 Try this code in php

```
function getMax($n1,$n2,$n3){
    if(($n1 >= $n2) && ($n1 >= $n3)){
      return $n1;
    } elseif (($n2 >= $n1) && ($n2 >= $n3)) {
      return $n2;
    } else {
      return $n3;
    }
  }

if(isset($_POST['submit']))//checks if form is submitted
   getMax($_POST['n1'],$_POST['n2'],$_POST['n3']);
```

I did not read exactly about your logic but your php code is missing some basic rules

Comment: He has `<input type="submit">` in his form, what's the problem with that? It doesn't need to have a name or value if he never uses `$_POST['submit']`.

Comment: You have lots of parenthesis problems in your function, and you never echo the result.

Comment: Sometimes it does not detect form in server side

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = [$_POST['n1'], $_POST['n2'], $_POST['n3']];
function getMax($arr) {
    $sorted = rsort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);
    return $sorted[0];
}
```

If you create an array outside your function it means you can feed in an array of any length you want and get the largest value, not just three elements (change `rsort()` to `sort()` to get the smallest.)

Run the PHP array sorting function `rsort()` which sorts the array from highest to lowest. Then return the first element which must be the highest value.

If you want to be especially picky, you can loop through all the $_POST values and check they are numbers with `is_numeric()` and only add them to the array if they are.

Note: I've used the >=PHP5.6 array notation, if you're using an older version use `array(1, 2, 3)`.